# how can i get the lower and upper value from the Filter bar in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the lower and upper value from this filter for searching in the database? This is the Picture of the Filter bar I used On my website.

[image]

This is the Html Code of that Filter Bar.

```
<div class="filter-price p-t-22 p-b-50 bo3">
  <div class="m-text15 p-b-17">
    Price
  </div>
  <div class="wra-filter-bar">
    <div id="filter-bar" id="value">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-sb-m flex-w p-t-16">
    <div class="w-size11">
      <!-- Button -->
      <button class="flex-c-m size4 bg7 bo-rad-15 hov1 s-text14 trans-0-4" class='filter'>
        Filter
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="s-text3 p-t-10 p-b-10">
      Range: $
      <span id="value-lower">610
      </span> - $
      <span id="value-upper">980
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the JQuery Code for this `Filter Bar`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*[ No ui ]
        ===========================================================*/
  var filterBar = document.getElementById('filter-bar');
  noUiSlider.create(filterBar, {
    start: [ 100, 2000 ],
    connect: true,
    range: {
      'min': 100,
      'max': 2000
    }
  }
                   );
  var skipValues = [
    document.getElementById('value-lower'),
    document.getElementById('value-upper')
  ];
  filterBar.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    skipValues[handle].innerHTML = Math.round(values[handle]) ;
  }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the software you're using is from [here](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/) then it just says you need to issue the get command, which for you would be like this:

filterBar.noUiSlider.get();

Since you're using a range then the get should return an array.  If you're not using that software, let me know.

**UPDATE**:
Here's one way to do what you want, where the button grabs the values from the slider.  Take note I had to change the markup of the button because you had two class attributes, so I changed class='filter' to id='filter'

```js
  var filterBar = document.getElementById('filter-bar');
  noUiSlider.create(filterBar, {
    start: [ 100, 2000 ],
    connect: true,
    range: {
      'min': 100,
      'max': 2000
    }
  });
  var skipValues = [
    document.getElementById('value-lower'),
    document.getElementById('value-upper')
  ];
  filterBar.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    skipValues[handle].innerHTML = Math.round(values[handle]) ;
  });
  
  $("button#filter").click(function () {
      var filterBar = document.getElementById('filter-bar');
      var vals = filterBar.noUiSlider.get();
      console.log(vals);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://refreshless.com/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.js"></script>
<link href="https://refreshless.com/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filter-price p-t-22 p-b-50 bo3">
  <div class="m-text15 p-b-17">
    Price
  </div>
  <div class="wra-filter-bar">
    <div id="filter-bar" id="value">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-sb-m flex-w p-t-16">
    <div class="w-size11">
      <!-- Button -->
      <button class="flex-c-m size4 bg7 bo-rad-15 hov1 s-text14 trans-0-4" id='filter'>
        Filter
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="s-text3 p-t-10 p-b-10">
      Range: $
      <span id="value-lower">610
      </span> - $
      <span id="value-upper">980
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the software you're using is from [here](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/) then it just says you need to issue the get command, which for you would be like this:

filterBar.noUiSlider.get();

Since you're using a range then the get should return an array.  If you're not using that software, let me know.

Comment: but how can I get values of this? Means when i click the Filter button so how can i get the min and max value?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example.  Check it out and let me know if you have any questions.